# Help solve glitchy RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Using the command

```
RegionPlot3D[Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] <= Abs[z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {LightBlue}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}]
```

The the plot is full of zigzas where it should not be

> [image]

Similar things happen when you draw another one,

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 <= z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {LightBlue}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}]
```

> [image]

I have adjust the anti-aliasing quality to the highest.
[image]

Comment: adding `PlotPoints -> 100` seems to fix first one. But it takes little longer to generate the plot now. Also for second one. Same thing. Add more points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContourPlot3D` generally works better than `RegionPlot3D` for this kind of thing, even without increasing `PlotPoints`. You just have to replace the inequalities with equations:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 Max[Abs[x], Abs[y]] == Abs[z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> {LightBlue}, BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> {LightBlue}, BoundaryStyle -> {Blue}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}]
```

[image]

As far as I can tell, the only reason to use `RegionPlot3D` is when it is not possible to use `ContourPlot3D` instead, i.e. when your condition cannot be expressed as $f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)$ for two continuous functions $f$ and $g$.